# How to pass pydantic create_model config and base arguments

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

It seems that pydantic does not allow passing both **base** and **config** arguments to create_model function, **to avoid confusion**.

What I tried to do is:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model

class Config:
    orm_mode = True

E = create_model('E', name='name', __base__=BaseModel)

B = create_model('B', age=1, __base__=E, __config__=Config)
```

Using classes this is very simple:

```
class E(BaseModel):
    name = 'name'

class B(E):
    age = 18

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Is there any way to do this using create_model?

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at [Pydantic tests - test_create_model.py](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/master/tests/test_create_model.py)
and found a simple test that demonstrates how to use Config and Base together:

```
def test_config_and_base():
    with pytest.raises(errors.ConfigError):
        create_model('FooModel', __config__=BaseModel.Config, __base__=BaseModel)
```

There are also other tests that demonstrate how to use Config class together with create_model()

```
def test_custom_config():
    class Config:
        fields = {'foo': 'api-foo-field'}

    model = create_model('FooModel', foo=(int, ...), __config__=Config)
    assert model(**{'api-foo-field': '987'}).foo == 987
    assert issubclass(model.__config__, BaseModel.Config)
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        model(foo=654)


def test_custom_config_inherits():
    class Config(BaseModel.Config):
        fields = {'foo': 'api-foo-field'}

    model = create_model('FooModel', foo=(int, ...), __config__=Config)
    assert model(**{'api-foo-field': '987'}).foo == 987
    assert issubclass(model.__config__, BaseModel.Config)
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        model(foo=654)


def test_custom_config_extras():
    class Config(BaseModel.Config):
        extra = Extra.forbid

    model = create_model('FooModel', foo=(int, ...), __config__=Config)
    assert model(foo=654)
    with pytest.raises(ValidationError):
        model(bar=654)
```

Comment: The first test you're mentioning expects a `ConfigError`. Using `create_model` like this is not allowed, that's exactly what OP is talking about 